# Acces value between two jsp with jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I create two jsp page with jstl and I want to retrieve data from the first page in the second.

In my first page i have

```
<c:out value="${cursor.getId_node() }"></c:out><br>
```

and I want this variable in my second page.

how can I do?

Thanks

Comment: So `cursor` is defined within the first jsp and you want to access it on the second?

Comment: How are you calling second jsp page from first jsp. Just set the value in request attribute and get in second jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code to access value between two jsp with jstl.

First JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<html>
  <body>
    This JSP stores the 'para' in a session-scoped variable where
    the other JSPs in the web application can access it.
    <p />
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="session"  />

     Click <a href="displayAttributes.jsp">here</a> to view it.
  </body>
</html>
```

Second JSP (displayAttributes.jsp)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Retrieval of attributes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    The para is <c:out value="${sessionScope.para}" /> <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Set the attribute in session scope

```
<c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="session"  />
```

Get the attribute from session scope

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.para}" />
```

---

More samples on other scopes.

```
    <%-- Set scoped variables --%>
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="page" />
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="request" />
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="session" />
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="application" />

    <%-- Print the values --%>
    <c:out value="${pageScope.para}" />
    <c:out value="${requestScope.para}" />
    <c:out value="${sessionScope.para}" />
    <c:out value="${applicationScope.para}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put the `value(cursor.getId_node())` in `'request'` scope and in second jsp , get the value from request