# how can i get parameter from post method in gwt

Tags: gwt

I have a html page and i am sending some parameter using post method.
now i want to get these parameter on gwt client. 
is there any method in gwt to get post parameter on client.?
i use following code

```
 <html>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/popnnn/js.html" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my gwt code

```
 TextBox text=new TextBox();
 text.setText(Window.Location.getParameter("foo"));
```

this is perfectly woking with get method but not with post 
please help......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to follow:

- Just convert the file `js.html` to `js.jsp`.
- Get the post parameter from the request parameter.
- Set the value in hidden div in JSP and access it in JAVA.
- Change the action attribute of form tag as shown below:

  ```
  <form action="http://localhost:8080/popnnn/js.jsp" method="post">
  ```

Try any one:

- [JSP Scriplets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html)

  ```
  <div id="fooParameter" style="visibility: hidden;">
       <%=request.getParameter("foo") %>
  </div>
  ```
- [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/)

  ```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
  <div id="fooParameter" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <c:out value="${param.foo}" />
  </div>
  ```

Access value from hosted HTML/JSP to JAVA code

```
String foo = RootPanel.get("fooParameter").getElement().getInnerHTML();

TextBox text=new TextBox();
text.setText(foo);
```

Find a sample code here about [Acces value between two jsp with jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546238/acces-value-between-two-jsp-with-jstl?answertab=votes#tab-top)