# how can i call a class java class from servlet

Tags: gwt

i hava a html page and hello is my servlet

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="http://localhost:8080/nitin/jsnipop/hello" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo">
 <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and my servlet is

```
public class hello  extends HttpServlet{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
{
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    String foo=req.getParameter("foo");   
    pw.println("Welcome "+foo);
}
}
```

now i want to send foo string variable on client side and set this as a user name
my client class name is ser.java
please help

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

- **Don't** write anything in response stream once request is forwarded to some one else.

There is no meaning of below line:

```
pw.println("Welcome "+foo);
```

because now the response is driven by forwarded JSP/Servlet/HTML.

- Classes that is shared between client and server must be placed under **shared** folder.

---

Steps to follow:

- Create an object of `Model` class that is placed under shared folder and just a POJO class.
- Set the properties in the object such as `username` etc.
- Set the object as `request attribute`.
- Forward the request to some one else
- Simply read it in forwarded JSP/Servlet.

Please have a look at below links to set and get the request attribute

- [Access value between two JSP with JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546238/acces-value-between-two-jsp-with-jstl?answertab=votes#tab-top)

---

Sample code:

hello Servlet (server side)

```
// get the parameter from the request
String foo=req.getParameter("foo");

// create an object of Model class
Model model = new Model();

// Set the properties in the object
model.setUserName(foo);

// set the object as request attribute
req.setAttribute("model",model);

// forward the request to some one else
rd.forward(req, res);
```

In forwarded JSP (using Scriplets)

```
<!-- Simply read it here -->
<%com.x.y.shared.Model model = request.getAttribute("model");%>
```

Model class (shared folder)

```
public class Model implements IsSerializable, Serializable{
    private String userName;

    public Model(){} // no-arg constructor
    // getter & setter
}
```

Comment: i want to set this in a text box and my have onmodule load function is this work

Comment: I have already shared you code. What was the issue with that code?

Comment: i can't use jsp help me with some other option. It will be vry kind of you

Comment: OK please tell me what is `rd` is here? where your request is forwarded?

Comment: its a object of dispeture class

Comment: I know it but where is it dispatching the request?

Comment: Tell me the flow. **HTML -> Servlet -> ?(What next here)**

Comment: my flow is HTMl -> Servlet-> model.java ( its a client Javaclass)

Comment: after following the above procedure i face (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/EntryPoint) this exception.

Comment: Please search on Google. It's very common issue in GWT.

Comment: Sorry you can't do it. Model is just like a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that is used to transfer the data between server and client. HTML -> Servlet(set model as request attribute) -> HTML/JSP(read model from the request)